# How to update specific item from the appState - ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

please I am trying to optimize the codes below. The dispatch isn't working and I am trying to avoid using the entire state as it may lead to redundancy and perhaps, want to enhance the code optimization. I am pretty sure there are mistakes but I couldn't figure it out. I have done it by updating the entire state, each time, I have to copy all the state while I want to dispatch some parts.
More also, I don't get any error... it is empty.

```
export interface AppState {
 id: number;
 name: string;
 education: Education;
 employment: Employment;

}
```

I have the interface for education as follows

```
export interface Education {
 id: number;
 school: School;
 graduatedYear: date;
 
}
```

The following is the school interface

```
export interface School {
  school_name: string
}
```

I am trying to update only the education at time and also feature select only the school.

```
export const initialState: AppState {
  id: 0,
  name: '',
  education: [{
      id: 0,
      school: '',
      GraduatedYear: ''
    }],
  employment: []
}
```

I tried to create an action as follows;

```
import { createAction, props} from '@ngrx/store';
import { Education } from './model'

export enum EducationUpdate {
    Update = '[Applicant Update] Update Education',
}

export const updateEducation = createAction(
    EducationUpdate.Update,
    props<{education: Education}> ()
);
```

Reducer

```
import { createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import { initialState } from "../actions/app.state";
import { Education } from './model'
import { updateEducation } from "../actions/education.action";


export const educationReducer = createReducer(
    initialState.education,
    on(
        updateEducation, (state , { education }): Education => education
        )
);
```

In my selector, I have the following.

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from './model';


export const educationSelector = createFeatureSelector<AppState>('education');
```

In app.module.ts file,

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ 
            education: educationReducer
         }),
```

I tried to dispatch but it's not working.

```
this.store.dispatch(updateEducation({education:{
      id: 1,
      school: 'Rockstar',
      GraduatedYear: '2011'
} }))
```

I am trying to target the specific variable i.e. education or employment and update it so that I wouldn't be updating the entire state as I have over 10 nested state within.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue... I was having a conflict in my **app.module.ts**. Instead, I am using *combineReducers*.